# What's the format of keras' matrix multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

All the math I've seen behind propagating data from one neural network layer to the next in calculating *z* looks like:

*z* = θ<sup>T</sup>x+b

but keras seems to diverge from that standard. It accepts its input matrices in the form of number of samples for rows and number of features for columns and the `get_weights()` command returns matrices with shapes that only satisfy the equation *z* if the following were true:

*z* = xθ+b

Given the following example of a network learning an XOR gate with input dimensions 4x2 and output dimensions 4x1:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np


X = np.array([[0,0],
              [1,0],
              [0,1],
              [1,1]])
Y = np.array([0,1,1,0])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100000, batch_size=4, verbose=0)

print model.get_weights()
print model.predict(X)
```

The model weights for each layer come out as 2x10, 10x10, and 10x1. The matrix multiplication fails to satisfy the first equation given for *z* but appears to work for the second. Does keras really handle its neural network computations this way or am I misinterpreting something in the code somewhere? Should my input X dimensions be transposed instead? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what `2` is doing here `Dense(10, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid')`? Think about the structure of the network

Comment: '2' is my number of parameters per x value, and it raises a value error for any number !=2. My question is trying to get at: does keras treat input X matrices as rows=number of training samples and columns=number of parameters? The format of the equation is incompatible with that based on the output dimensions of the weights.

Answer (score 1):

This all goes as expected. Please take a look at the code written [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py), and search for the Dense class.

To make it a bit easier.. here are two important snippets of the code. 
This is how the kernel is build

```
 input_dim = input_shape[-1]

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units),
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='kernel',
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
```

And this is how the multiplication is done

```
def call(self, inputs):
    output = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
```

If you consider this approach, how your weights, input_dims, etc. are defined, it then all makes perfect sense.
If not, please leave a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the way to setup your weights (shape). Take a look at this example, taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/stewartpark/187895beb89f0a1b3a54):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np 

X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X, y, show_accuracy=True, batch_size=1, nb_epoch=1000)
print(model.predict_proba(X))
"""
[[ 0.0033028 ]
 [ 0.99581173]
 [ 0.99530098]
 [ 0.00564186]]
"""
```

Comment: Yes, that's a better way to set up the architecture of the network. Interestingly, it works regardless if Y is a 4x1 or a 1x4 matrix. With this network however the problem remains: X is a 4x2 matrix and the dimensions of the first weight matrix are 2x10. Those dimensions are incompatible if it were calculating $\theta^T x$ given the dimensions (10x2) and (4x2).

Comment: Interesting. What I can tell you now is that you are right, and this transposition is happening somewhere in the code. I have to go through keras' code in Github to find this out. If you need a fast answer, move this Q to stackoverflow or as a similar one there. I'm sure developers of keras will answer it pretty fast.

Comment: Aslo, do note that tensorflow is doing what you're expecting it to do. Magic is happening in Keras. Nobody is going to mess with matmul like that. The only reason for something like that happening could be for speed improvement. Try to benchmark it for your self or ask a question on SO to see if that's the case